# Dissolving plastic resin without damaging aluminium surface

Tags: metal, solvents, plastics

I have an aluminium surface covered with some plastic, which I intend to dissolve in order to clean the surface. On the note for the plastic I have applied, it says that it contains the following:

- 2-butanone Naphtha
- Hexane
- Toluene
- Resins

What solvent would you recommend to dissolve this plastic, without damaging the aluminium underneath? Could I simply reapply the solvents that were used initially (naphta, hexane, toluene and the ketone)? Regular petrol should contain up to 15% of the toluene, would it be safe to clean it with petrol?

Comment: This isn't what plastic is made of, more like a composition for casting, well, a resin. All other components are solvents and stabilizers, so first I'd try literally one the components you've listed. And VM&P and Naphtha should be together: [it's one of the trade names for petroleum ether](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/npg/npgd0664.html).